# Magento 2 : How to add category selector on admin form?

Tags: magento-2.1, adminform, category-tree

I want to add a category selector on a new tab in my admin form. Please help me to do the same or provide me a suitable tutorial.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to add tree input renderer you can add this code in your ui component form xml

```
<field name="parent">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\Form\Categories\Options</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Parent Category</item>
            <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/js/components/new-category</item>
            <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data.parent</item>
            <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="levelsVisibility" xsi:type="number">1</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
            <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
            <item name="listens" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="${ $.namespace }.${ $.namespace }:responseData" xsi:type="string">setParsed</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

Comment: Is it necessary to add admin form using ui component? Now I am not using ui component form ,that's why I asked.

Comment: Ok .Let me start creating form using ui component.

Comment: How can i save the selected categories to my db ?

Comment: when you post your form you will get values of selected categories in form of array. You can implode it and save it in form of comma separated values

Comment: Does $data['parent'] in save.php contains that array?

Comment: Hello @userpk, I have also added category tree and also add code for saving values in comma separated but how to render in edit form back?

Comment: I am also facing rendering back issue